# App hangs when executing the query in prepared statement

Tags: select, db2, execute, freeze

I am trying to select rows which are older than 7 days from current date. Database used is DB2 version 9.

Can you please tell me how exactly can I use the datetime in the query? The date table field is of type timestamp.

I am able to manually run the query without issues. However, when I am using in the prepared statement,
 The app hangs when executing the query result = pselect.executeQuery(); as a result of which we need to restart db2 instance in order to clear it. 
 Can you please help what might be the issue? I do not see any exceptions at all. Other parts of the code works fine if I remove the select_query part.

```
try{
    String select_query = "SELECT URL_ID ,URLVAL FROM URL_TAB WHERE " +
                  "UPDATED_DATE < TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAYS, '00.00.00')";
    System.out.println("select_query=" + select_query);

    conn = JDBCDataObjectFactoryManager
            .getConnection("JDBCConnectionFactory-SDE");

    pselect = conn.prepareStatement(select_query);
    System.out.println("pselect=" + pselect);

try{    
    System.out.println("inside try");   
    result = pselect.executeQuery();        
    System.out.println("result=" + result);
}catch(Exception e){ 
    System.out.println("inside catch"); 

    System.out.println("error message==============>"+e.getMessage());

}

if ((result != null) && (result.next())) {
            System.out.println("3 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

             url_id = result.getInt(1);
             url = result.getString(2);
}//end if
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities: either the query is in a lock wait, or it runs for so long that it appears to be hung.

Check what is the value of LOCKWAIT database configuration parameter --by default it is -1, which means infinity, and you normally want to set it to a more reasonable value, typically 30 or 60 seconds. If it is the lock wait that causes your application to "hang", you would get an exception instead, which will help you to debug further.

If the issue is caused by the poor query performance, you'll need to work with your DBAs to figure out the root cause and resolve it.

Comment: There is only 1 matching row and total of 4 records in the table. So I believe it may not be performance issue. I sometimes see the exception may be 2/10 times. So finding it difficult to trace what is the root cause. DBA says it is application error.

Comment: I will check on the LOCKWAIT parameter value and set it to 60 sec and see what happens. Thanks mustaccio.

Comment: What happens if you run that query from the command line? You could also try looking at the JDBC trace -- [see here how to turn it on](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/t0020709.html) -- for additional clues.